# Trying to read a text file content and set variables values from that

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file that creates a text file with its output like the following:

```
RESULT=0&SECURETOKEN=SmH3kciXiVkiwD0i70CwKYgAR&SECURETOKENID=2013031414280240&RESPMSG=Approved
```

The length of the variables is constant, so it is easy to parse the value from the string. Delimits for all name-value pairs are ampersands.

Then, from within the first batch file, I need to call another batch file and use two variable values from the text file content:

```
SECURETOKEN
```

and

```
SECURETOKENID
```

Using the following part in the second batch does not help, where Temp_result.txt is the file that contains the output.

```
set /p out=<{full path to the file}\Temp_result.txt
set SECURETOKEN=%out~21,25%
set SECURETOKENID=%out~61,16%
```

Can anybody help me out, please?

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the `:` after your variable name. So your commands would be:

```
set /p out=<{full path to the file}\Temp_result.txt
set SECURETOKEN=%out:~21,25%
set SECURETOKENID=%out:~61,16%
```

Comment: these are working perfectly. 
Thank you very much. I overlooked the colon


   set /p out=<{full path to the file}\Temp_result.txt

   set SECURETOKEN=%out:~21,25%

   set SECURETOKENID=%out:~61,16%

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have a perfectly fine solution with the user1936123 answer. Here is a completely different approach that will work even if the value lengths are not constant.

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /f "usebackq tokens=2,3 delims=&" %%A in ("{fullFilePath}\Temp_result.txt") do (
  set "%%A"
  set "%%B"
)
```

If you are willing to set a variable for all of the name value pairs, not just the 2nd and 3rd ones, then:

```
set /p "ln=" <"{fullFilePath}\Temp_result.txt"
set "%ln:&="&set "%"
```

It is not obvious how the above works. It uses search and replace to transform the line into the following series of SET statements, that are then executed:

```
set "RESULT=0"&set "SECURETOKEN=SmH3kciXiVkiwD0i70CwKYgAR"&set "SECURETOKENID=2013031414280240"&set "RESPMSG=Approved"
```